# Error in setting Path for "ant" on Mac ( Cordova )

Tags: android, cordova, ant

This is how I have set path on bash_profile file for my Cordova Project

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Work/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Work/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools

export ANT_HOME=/Users/Work/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730

export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

When I try to run " **cordova platform add android** ", I got

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
```

Comment: Why do you have ant in the adt-bundle? Try downloading a standalone version instead of using an eclipse plugin version.

Comment: Thats the good idea.... Am trying that now... may be u should have put that has answer. I would give u one up and mark as answer If this clicks..

Comment: Hey, great I'm glad it worked. I added it as an answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading a standalone version of ANT instead of using the one that comes packaged as an Eclipse plugin. The plugin version might be modified to run with Eclipse or might otherwise have some differences that are causing problems. Additionally, I'd think that a standalone version will be easier to upgrade.

On my machine, I'm running ant 1.8.4 - your plugin seems to be ant 1.8.3, so that might be what's causing the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

Install ant using brew.

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.

Comment: Since tried MBillau's suggestion and worked out for me I marked his post as answer. I have problem with brew, I tried brew earlier and it kept showing some bug now and then. So am no more using brew. But thank u so much for your time to help. May your answer help someone in the future, who comes up with query like mine.